# Can I use the metadata API to check if an instance is being terminated?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Using Windows server 2016 instances.

I want the instance to run a local command before it terminates.

I can have a script run when windows is shutting down.

I would like the script to check if the instance itself is in the terminating state and if so run some clean up stuff.

Not sure from the docs, is there a way to check if the local instance is being terminated from the instance itself?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-categories

This returns InstanceStatuses:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --include-all-instances --instance-ids i-123123123
```

Which looks like:

```
{
    "InstanceStatuses": [
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2a",
            "InstanceId": "i-123123123",
            "InstanceState": {
                "Code": 16,
                "Name": "running"
            },
            "InstanceStatus": {
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Name": "reachability",
                        "Status": "passed"
                    }
                ],
                "Status": "ok"
            },
            "SystemStatus": {
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Name": "reachability",
                        "Status": "passed"
                    }
                ],
                "Status": "ok"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What does the state looks like when the instance is "terminating"? Not already terminated but pending termination? How can I check if an instance is in the pending termination state?

Comment: Not according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-status.html).

Comment: yup there is no terminating state only "shutting down"

Answer (score 1):

What you're calling the `terminating state` AWS refers to as `shutting-down`.

You can use `describe-instances` and use `--query` or `jq` to parse out the information you want.

**Example with --query:**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-070ca5c669933b949 --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].State.Code
```

Will return the instance status code (details below):

> [
>       48
>   ]

**Example with jq:**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-070ca5c669933b949 |jq .Reservations[].Instances[].State.Code
```

**Outputs:**

> 48

You can also get the output in text:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-070ca5c669933b949 |jq .Reservations[].Instances[].State.Name
```

Will output:

> "terminated"

Below is the pertinent Output from the command and the codes that correspond to instance state:

```
State -> (structure)
    The current state of the instance.

    Code -> (integer)
        The low byte represents the state. The high byte is used for internal purposes and should be ignored.

        0 : pending
        16 : running
        32 : shutting-down
        48 : terminated
        64 : stopping
        80 : stopped
    Name -> (string)
        The current state of the instance.
```

**References**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html